# Pointer to array of pointers

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with c++ pointers. I have a pointer to array of pointers.
and the case is:

```
MyType *(*arr)[5];
MyType **a = arr;
```

the 2nd line gives an error. How can i take pointer to this array ?

Comment: Avoid pointer at all cost. Vector in c++ should be either std::vector or std::array.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which array are you talking about? _arr_ is a pointer, not an array. _arr_ points to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all (include it in your question the next time).

You declare *a pointer to array of five pointers to MyType*. Then you try to assign it to *pointer-to-pointer-to  MyType*. This is exactly what error message says:

```
IntelliSense: a value of type "MyType *(*)[5]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int **"
```

Another suggestion is to tell, what you are trying to achieve. Though my explanation is technically correct, I doubt it will solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
int* arr[8]; // An array of int pointers.
int (*arr)[8]; // A pointer to an array of integers
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `arr` is a pointer which points to an array of pointers. So if you want to take pointer to the array, use `MyType **a=*(arr+i)` where `*(arr+i)` is the `i th` array.